PowerBI Api Get Access Token
I want automatic login to view power bi reports with iframe in mvc application.
For this, I created an application in Azure AD and gave all read permissions in the delegated permissions.
For this i created a class and get access token. But when i call service with token i get unauthorized error.
The class I created is as follows;
 public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
 {
     IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
         .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
         .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
         .Build();


     string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" };
     AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
     Console.WriteLine("token: " + result.AccessToken);
     return result.AccessToken;
 }


 public async Task<string> GetReportsAsync()
 {
     string accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();

     using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports");
     return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 }

How can I solve this problem?

This api call gets the reports from My Workspace:
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports
However since the application registration doesn't have a personal workspace, an error is returned.

I recommend using this api call instead:
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports/{reportId}
This call returns an embed url that can be used to embed the Power BI report directly into your application.
